# Is it dangerous to run tall rides in a thunderstorm?

Tags: rollercoaster-tycoon-2

In the real world, when there is a thunderstorm at an amusement park, all rides except for flat rides close down for safety, to prevent anyone from getting hurt in a freak lightning strike, and also to prevent the ride from breaking down in the rain, simply because most amusement rides were not designed to run in the rain.

Do these weather concerns hold true in Roller Coaster Tycoon 2 as well, or is a temporary decrease in popularity the only effect of weather?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No thunder storms are just for mood. People will leave your park sooner though and get unhappy thoughts. On the other hand you get to sell them umbrella's.